# What is the difference between initiating a vector as vector < class > ( value ) and vector < class > [ value ]

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std

When my initialization is : 
`vector < pair < int , int > > v ( 100 );` 
i can't execute : 
`vecini[x].push_back( make_pair( y , z ) ) ;` 
but it works when i initiate it like: 
`vector < pair < int , int > > v [100];`

Comment: Do you want a vector of 100 elements or 100 empty vectors?

Comment: The first one is a vector of 100 `(0,0)` pairs. The second one is an array of 100 empty vectors.

Comment: I wanted an array of 100 empty vectors, but thought that both of the initializations did the same thing. Thank you !

Comment: You *think* you want an array of 100 empty vectors, but that's a bad idea. Instead start with a *vector* of 100 empty vectors of pairs. `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>> v(100);`. The best thing to do is define meaningfully named types, e.g. `struct point { int x, int y };` instead of `std::pair<int, int>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vector>v(100); initialize a vector of 100 elements where each element is of type pair with all values initialized to 0

vector>v[100]; initializes an array of 100 elements where each element is a vector of type pair

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing apples and bananas here: vector initialization and C style array.

```
using type = vector<pair<int, int>>;
type x(100); // <- single vector with 100 elements in it
type y[100]; // <- array of 100 vectors, with 0 elements in each
```